# Unable to switch between open emails

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007

Using Outlook 2007 (SP 2) + Windows XP (SP3)

Opening several emails places these on the task bar as normal, however, if I click on an email this does not release focus when I click on another open email on the taskbar.

The original email persists with the selected email flashing briefly on screen and then disappearing again.

Double clicking on an email to switch focus only works 75% of the time?

All other Windows programs work normally and switch focus as required?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the problematic window has opened a `Dialog` - therefore you cannot go to another open Email window.

I have experienced it before. All the open email windows are on the same "level" as the one that opened the `Dialog` - so until the `Dialog` is not closed, you cannot switch to any of the open email windows.

Answer (score 1):

I started encountering the same issue today after installing several Windows Updates (KBs), some of which are targetted towards Outlook.

The issue occurs in the absence of any open Dialog.

I uninstalled KB2553971 (Junk Email Filter: OUTLFLTR) and it resolved the issue for me.